# Proving equality between Dafny set comprehensions

Tags: dafny

I'm having trouble proving equality between set comprehensions.
Dafny is unable to prove that the two set comprehensions within the calc statement
are equivalent.

What's a good strategy to work around this?  Or am I doing something wrong here?

```
datatype Wrap = wrap(v: nat)

lemma minimal_reproduction(L: nat)
    {
        calc {
            set n: nat | n < L :: n;
            set n: nat | n < L :: wrap(n).v;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hover (in vscode) over first set comprehension, you can see dafny is showing
warning that no terms found to trigger on. Roughly it means dafny will not generate terms of form `x in (set n: nat | n < L :: n)` during proof search. Since Set equality is assertion of form `S == T <==> forall x :: x in S <==> x in T`, not able to generate terms of form `x in S` impedes automatic proof.

There are various heuristics dafny uses to find trigger
which you can read it [here](https://pit-claudel.fr/clement/papers/dafny-trigger-selection-CAV16.pdf).
Common strategy to avoid this is wrap literals in Identity function.

```
datatype Wrap = wrap(v: nat)

function Identity(n: nat) : nat { n }

lemma minimal_reproduction(L: nat)
{
 calc {
   set n: nat | n < L :: Identity(n);
   set n: nat | n < L :: wrap(n).v;
 }
}
```

This still doesn't verify as triggers for sets are disjoint. Calling Identity
on parameter of wrap make dafny select `Identity` as trigger for second set
comprehension, now it verifies.

```
lemma minimal_reproduction(L: nat)
{
 calc {
   set n: nat | n < L :: Identity(n);
   set n: nat | n < L :: wrap(Identity(n)).v;
 }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for this clear explanation.

Comment: So now I run into the problem that I have to prove that inserting the Identity is equivalent i.e. `set n: nat | n < L :: Identity(n) == set n: nat | n < L :: n`, which then brings be back to the initial problem of it not triggering again.   Should I try manual triggers to get around this or is there a better approach?

Comment: I was wondering about this problem when I was writing this answer. Manual trigger does not solve this, I don't know why. On deeper level it is matter of interpretation if you are ok with replacing literals x with Identity(x) and call those specification equal.

Answer (score 1):

The below code seems to work and also solves quickly, however I don't understand why this solution is working well.

```
datatype Wrap = wrap(v: nat)

lemma minimal_reproduction(L: nat)
    ensures (set n: nat | n < L :: n) == (set n: nat | n < L :: wrap(n).v)
    {
        var s1 := (set n: nat | n < L :: n);
        var s2 := (set n: nat | n < L :: wrap(n).v);
        assert s2 == set x | x in s1 :: wrap(x).v;
    }
}
```